# How to handle too many SQL Connections?

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to develop a server for a mobile game which should be able to withstand 1000 simultaneous connections. The Server is connected to a MySQL Database and each time I am looking to access the database I enclose my SQLConnection Cmd and Reader with a using statement so that they are all opened briefly and closed afterwards:

```
using (MySqlConnection SQLToUse = CreateSQLConnection()) {
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, SQLToUse);
   ...
}
```

I had problems with readers which is why I had to do this.
Theoretically, if say 1000 users were to open SQL Connections simultaneously, the maximum amount of SQL connections (151 to my knowledge) would stop me from creating any more connections and throw an error. This hasn’t happened yet because the highest number of users the server ever had at once was 10, but i am asking how to prevent it.
Thank you for reading this all the way through and for your help in advance

Comment: this sounds like object pooling

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a service part that keep the connection(s) open and then the other part of the game make requests to this part. (sort of how you use a library)

I would also suggest you add a stack and each time a query is done it can check the stack for another query to run. Each time something is added to the stack, check if there is any connections available, if there are activate a connection that will pick up the new line in the stack.

Very hard to describe the code with no information on what languages is used but this should get you in the right direction.